# Cannot import a component inside another component in lwc

Tags: lightning-web-components, import

I have my main component (cmp1) and another 3 other components (helpers/services, they dont have html, only js). 
In cmp1 I'm calling helper1 that calls helper2

cmp1->helper1->*helper2*

helper1 throws error

> helper2.initializeContext is not a function

Im importing with `import {initializeContext} from 'c/helper2'` notation and helper2 have lwc class structure but helper1 dont (its similar to mortgage.js, only methods with export).

I've tried to import with but still not working

> import initializeContext from '../helper2/helper2.js'

Helper2

```
    import { LightningElement, api, wire, track } from "lwc";

export default class sheetHelper extends LightningElement {
    @api context;`

    initializeContext(parentsContext) {
        this.context = parentsContext;
    }
```

Helper1

```
    import { initializecontext } from 'c/helper2';
    function initialize(parentsContext) {
        initializeContext(parentsContext); <-throw error
        ...
    }
    ...
    export { initialize }
```

Main component

```
import { initialize } from 'c/helper1';

export default class PedidosExcelDealer extends LightningElement {

    renderedCallback() {
        initialize(this.template);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to SFSE. Could you please add the code from helper2 (the basic function declaration - you can omit the body - and the export statements) along with how you try to import and use it in helper1 by [editing](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/286837/edit) your question. It is always best to follow the guidelines in [How to Ask](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) when writing your questions. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I've edited my post. Hope this might help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To define and import a value or function the code to import would look e.g. like this:

```
// Reason enum
const Reason = Object.freeze({
    ADOPTION: { name: 'adoption', label: 'Adoption/foster care'},
    BEREAVEMENT: {name: 'bereavement', label: 'Bereavement'},
    ...
});

const reasonFromName = (name) => {
    return Object.values(Reason).find(value => value.name === name);
};

export {
    Reason,
    reasonFromName
};
```

and you could import it and use it e.g. like this:

```
import { LightningElement, api } from 'lwc';
import { reasonFromName } from 'c/shared';

export default class IntakeReason extends LightningElement {

    @api reason;

    change(event) {
        this.reason = reasonFromName(event.target.value);
        this.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('reason'));
    }
}
```

In your code, the `initializeContext` method is a class method i.e. only makes sense via an instance of a `LightningElement`.

You could use inheritance, but note this from the Salesforce documentation:

> Inheritance is allowed, but it isn’t recommended because composition
>   is usually more effective. To share logic between components, use a
>   module that contains only logic. See [Additional JavaScript Files for
>   Sharing Code](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.create_components_javascript_share). If you do choose to use inheritance, note that it
>   doesn’t work across namespaces.